# Build complete and running but showing error on class android

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

i have some strange error / bug on android studio, my application gradle is complete and running smoothly on device but its showing error like my library is not completely include on android studio, i already do

1. Clean then Rebuild
2. Invalidate Cache and restart

but nothing work, this is the screenshot
[image: Error importing and everything who use the class]

[image: Success gradle]

This is My App Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.host.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

and this is my project gradle

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So i can run my application, i can use it but its really disturbing for me to do code because i cannot use autocomplete regarding the error libs and red marks everywhere .

Thank You..

Comment: remove those statements which are showing error and re-import .

Comment: try **removing all dependencies then sync** and **add all dependencies again then sync**

Comment: @nimi0112 & AliAhmed  thank you so much, its worked. You all save my time a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the lines and re-import them from correct/compatible packages.
2. Try removing all dependencies then sync and add all dependencies again then sync.

As you mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53553341/6549598) [nimi0112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6549598/nimi0112) and [Ali Ahmed's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10406163/ali-ahmed) your answer is really helped me a lot.